# Charging voltage across VM and VSS of AP9221SA-CC-HAC-7 is 0.6V even when USB charger is inserted

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, protection, pmic

I am using **AP9221SA-CC-HAC-7** PCM IC with 1-cell Li-ion battery (4.2V). I have battery charger (**RT9471**) after PCM IC and load connected after battery charger. The PACK+ and PACK- signals go the the battery charger supply pins. Load is never disconnected in this system. The part of schematic is as shown in the image attached.

[image]
[image]

Now, my battery is discharged to 2.957V. According to the datasheet of AP9221SA-CC-HAC-7, it is between Over discharge upper threshold (2.97V) and lower threshold range (2.85V) so it should be in Over-discharge state. When I measured voltage across PAC+ and PACK-, I observed a voltage of 0.07V.The system was not functioning as input supply to battery voltage is low in this case (0.07V).

I inserted a USB Type-C Charger which supplies the charging voltage to the VBUS pin of Battery charger. Still the battery is not charging (when voltage measured across CN2). At this time, when I measured the voltage across PACK+ and PACK- the voltage was 0.6V.The voltage at REGN pin of battery charger was 5.0V I left the Charger connected to the system for about an hour and then measured voltage across PACK+ and PACK-, it remained at 2.957V.

I also bypassed PCM by connecting VSS and PACK-. At this time battery started to charge. I again connected a battery of 2.957V and inserted charger (USB Type-C). Now the battery charged (Voltage increased).

[image]

**Now my question is:**

1. Why is battery not charging when PMIC is present and Charger is inserted?
2. Why the voltage at PACK+ and PACK- o.6V when charger is inserted?

Please help me on this one. Also I chose AP9221SA-CC-HAC-7 as there were internal FETs present and my board has space constraint issue.

AP9221SA-CC-HAC-7 Datasheet: https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0012884324_1-2543822.pdf

RT9471D Datasheet: https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9471=RT9471D/DS9471D-02.pdf